# How to send third-part csd to '/opt/cloudera/csd' nicely?

Tags: cloudera, cloudera-cdh

It's bad action to put csd into path '/opt/cloudera/csd' of cm by backend ops which need the password of the server of cm.
Is there a way cdh offered to make it like distribute the parcel package?

Answer (score 0):

No, CSD must be added only on Cloudera Manager Node on /opt/cloudera/csd
Parcel will be deployed on the parcel folder